# Concatenate the lists inside a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I want to "concatenate" 2 lists of the form `[[a], [b], [c], ...]` and `[[e], [f], [g], ...]` to obtain a list `[[a,e], [b,f], [c,g], ...]`. The lengths of the 2 lists (n lists) will always be the same. How can I do this? I'm new to Python :(

Comment: Take a look at the Python `zip` (as in zipper) function, and I think you will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you use zip to iterate through the elements of both list at same time, then add them together (list+list = concatenate the 2 list), and finaly append the result to a third list (concatenated list):

Something like this:

```
l1, l2 = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['e'], ['f'], ['j']]
concat = []
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    concat.append(i + j)
print(concat)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_